# Why is the first derivative of a scalar-valued function with respect to a vector its gradient?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, machine-learning

To train a word2vec model (vector representations of word meanings) the following expression needs to be optimized:

$$p(\text{context words}| \text{current word}) = \frac{\exp(u_o^\top v_c)}{\sum_{w_i = 1}^V\exp(u_o^\top v_c)}$$

where $u_w$ and $u_o$ are matrices of context word vectors and $v_c$ is the current word.

Above expression can be rewritten as $$\log \exp(u_o^\top v_c) - \log \sum_{w_i = 1}^V\exp(u_o^\top v_c) = u_o^\top v_c - \sum_{w_i = 1}^V\exp(u_o^\top v_c)$$

Now the gradient of that function needs to be found to improve the model.

In the [source I am consulting](https://youtu.be/ERibwqs9p38?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5Jsnh1rnUwq_TcylNr7EkRe6&t=3224) finding the gradient starts by finding the derivative of the expression $u_o^\top v_c$ with respect to $v_c$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} u_o \bullet v_c = u_o
\end{align*}

I don't understand what is being done there. As far as I know $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}f$ is one of the many ways to denote the directional derivative. But that does not seem to be what it is. When I searched for "derivative with respect to vector" I found the claim

(1)

> The first derivative of a scalar-valued function $f$ with respect to a vector is called the gradient of $f$

[ https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0471705195.app3 ]

That seems to fit the bill, as $p$ is scalar valued.

I also found

(2)

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (a column vector) and let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. The derivative of $f$ with respect to x is the $m \times n$ matrix $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = $ [...] . $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is called the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

[ http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf ]

That seems to be the generalization of (1).

(3)

> $\frac{d f}{d v} = \left[ \frac{d f}{d v_1}, \dots, \frac{d f}{d v_n}\right]^\top$ where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$

[ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWxY7VdcSH8 ]

I am still somewhat lost here, anyway. Can you maybe tell me

1) which if any of the above cases is applied here

2) **why (1) actually is true** (primary question, if actually what happens here)

3) what I need to look for to learn more about derivatives with respect to vectors, as I did not find a lot more than the above three claims.

Also I am a little irritated about his use of the chain rule in [the next steps of the manipulation](https://youtu.be/ERibwqs9p38?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5Jsnh1rnUwq_TcylNr7EkRe6&t=3369). He rewrites

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v_c} \log \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)$$

as

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)} \frac{\partial}{\partial v_c} \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c) $$

Why can he do that? According to (3) I would have expected

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v_c} \log \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)
&= \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial v_{c_1}} \log \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)\\
    \vdots\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial v_{c_n}} \log \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)} \frac{\partial}{\partial v_{c_1}} \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)\\
    \vdots\\
    \frac{1}{\sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)} \frac{\partial}{\partial v_{c_n}} \sum_{w=1}^V \exp(u_o^\top v_c)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

which, if I am not mistaken, does in the end yield the same final result as in the video, but I would like to know if his shortcut has a general form with a proof.